# Angular does ngif only compute if in view

Tags: angular

I have a component that shows an icon if a variable is true using ngif. I noticed that when I try to print the page, only the parts that are visible before scrolling down have the icon when the variable is true.

So then does ngIf "lazy computes" or could it be a different error?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "print the page"?

1. Are you trying to use the browser API Print -> Save as PDF for
   example?
2. Or you mean printing on console?

In first case is not related to ngIf. I tried this:

```
 <div id="printId">
  <span *ngFor="let num of casualArr">
    <p *ngIf="isTrue" style="margin: 40px;">{{num}}</p>
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <button (click)="print()">Print</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  isTrue = true;
  casualArr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24];



 print() {
    const contentToPrint = document.getElementById("printId");
    const wnd = window.open();
    wnd!.document.write(contentToPrint!.innerHTML);
    wnd!.document.close();
    wnd!.focus();
    wnd!.print();
    wnd!.close();
  }
```

And when trying to print/Save as PDF clicking on Print button, is showing all page. Doing the same thing using browser API so Right click -> Print -> Save as PDF... it's showing only the visible page without scrolling. You should personalize this using a personalized css stylesheet for printing. And i repeat, this has nothing to do with *ngIf